# Combine two SQL statements into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to solve the following problem.

I have two SQL statements:

```
SELECT TagID, TagTitle, 
COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
FROM TagCategories 
JOIN SocialAndTags 
ON SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID = TagID
JOIN SocialManagementTracker 
ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialID 
WHERE InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID

SELECT TagID, TagTitle, 
COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
FROM TagCategories 
JOIN SocialAndTags 
ON SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID_OtherA = TagID
JOIN SocialManagementTracker 
ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialID 
WHERE InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
```

The first query gives the following results, which are correct:

```
TagID | TagTitle | TagCount
1     | PASO     | 26
2     | TUIT     | 1
3     | AST      | 3
4     | IS       | 3
10    | NA       | 17
20    | PSE      | 3
21    | CO       | 40
```

The second query gives the following results, which are also correct:

```
TagID | TagTitle | TagCount
1     | PASO     | 14
2     | TUIT     | 3
4     | IS       | 3
20    | PSE      | 13
22    | NONE     | 55
23    | Digital  | 2
24    | PCC      | 3
```

What I need to happen is have both results appear in one query, but I seem to be at a loss on how to do this.

My last query was:

```
SELECT TagTitle,
COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
FROM TagCategories
LEFT OUTER JOIN SocialAndTags AS OtherA ON OtherA.TagCategoriesID = TagID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SocialAndTags AS OtherB ON OtherB.TagCategoriesID_OtherA = TagID
GROUP BY TagTitle
```

Some of the results were correct, but others were way off. As an example,
PASO results was 364 and it should be 40
TUIT results was 3 and it should be 4

Alternatively, the results for 
Digital were 2, which is correct
NONE were 55, which is also correct

Clearly I've done something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for a total across the two results? I think the 1 to many relationship is messing up your joins.

Comment: Exactly. Just need the totals added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this.

```
SELECT TagID, TagTitle, 
COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
FROM TagCategories 
    JOIN SocialAndTags ON (SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID = TagID OR SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID_OtherA = TagID)
    JOIN SocialManagementTracker ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialID 
WHERE InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
```

Comment: Can both columns have the same tag?

Comment: I've seen performance issues caused by `OR`.  The `OR` can cause the query optimizer to choose a table scan instead of concatenating separate index seeks.  I would recommend making it separate queries with a `UNION` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with UNION, between the two SELECTs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thats what we had originally, but they want all the results added together.

Comment: Ok what about a nested SELECT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can union the queries together and get the sum of the counts.  For example:

```
SELECT TagID, TagTitle, SUM(TagCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT TagID, TagTitle, COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
    FROM TagCategories 
    JOIN SocialAndTags ON SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID = TagID
    JOIN SocialManagementTracker ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialID 
    WHERE InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
    GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TagID, TagTitle, COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
    FROM TagCategories 
    JOIN SocialAndTags ON SocialAndTags.TagCategoriesID_OtherA = TagID
    JOIN SocialManagementTracker ON SocialAndTags.SMTrackerID = SocialID 
    WHERE InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
    GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
) BothCounts
GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT TagTitle,
COUNT(*) AS TagCount 
FROM TagCategories
JOIN SocialAndTags AS OtherA 
ON OtherA.TagCategoriesID = TagID
JOIN SocialAndTags AS OtherB 
ON OtherB.TagCategoriesID_OtherA = TagID
WHERE OtherA.InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND OtherA.InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
AND OtherB.InitialComment > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND OtherB.InitialComment < '2020-03-25 23:59:59.999' 
GROUP BY TagTitle, TagID
```